# How to Fix Login Issues for a Remote "Managed, Mobile" User

Tags: mojave, user-account, active-directory

Managed, Mobile account will not successfully login without first logging into a local admin account and then switching users to the Managed, Mobile account.

Is there anything that I could check or do to resolve login issues?

**Scope**

- macOS connects to a network account server: domain.local
- Successful login to Managed, Mobile user displays message `There was a problem connecting to the server "domain.local". the server may not exist or it is unavailble at this time. Check the server name or IP address, check your network connection, and then try again`
- AD DomainMode: Windows2008R2Domain
- AD ForestMode: Windows2003Forest

Comment: .local is no RFC-compliant tld (and domain.local no fqdn!) It's reserved for mDNS. Please add some more details (e.g AD/Windows Server version etc.).

Comment: Thank you. Sorry to cause confusion here ```domain.local``` is a variable backed up by the actual companies domain name. I can't disclose the actual domain name, but it's a real FQDN name.

Comment: even a split horizon env (e.g internal: ibm.local and external: ibm.com) leads to a mess with macOS clients... any sldn.local is just no-go

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the Scope with more accurate information. Would the fix then be to point the network account server option in users and groups to an actual server/IP?

Comment: or just in general I need to setup a local user account for this user? This login type was working for the user previously, but now they can only login if there is a different local user logged in at the same time. It seems to work when they switch user from the local to the Manged, Mobile account.

Comment: I have to test this first...takes a while. Are the Macs encrypted?

Comment: System Preferences> Security> file vault is ```active``` for the Manged, Mobile user account. Let me know if I need to get this information from another location.Thank you